# Radio buttons and figures

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm new to Android Studio and I want to create this LinearLayout section in my application. As you could see, every radio button has a belonging figure to it. The problem is that the figure is too wide, I want every figure to get a smaller width. This is my code below, do you have any suggestions for better solutions?

Thanks in advance!

[Screenshot of code in app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTe7E.png)
x

````
 <LinearLayout style="@style/Row">
                <TextView style="@style/RowLabel" android:text="Select type:"
                    android:textSize="20dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ln_layout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="103dp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/txt1"
                    android:layout_width="1dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_patrols" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/txt2"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_patrols" />

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/txt3"
                    android:layout_width="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:layout_marginHorizontal="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/menu_patrols"
                    android:gravity="center" />
            </LinearLayout>```
````

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to do this. One way is to give padding to your `LinearLayout`. Use `paddingHorizontal` attribute.

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ln_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="103dp"
        android:paddingHorizontal="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
```

Sample Output :
Previous Layout :

[image: Original]

Modified Layout:

[image: Modified]

Comment: If this helped you can mark the answer as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Adjust the android:layout_width:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/txt1"
    android:layout_width="50dp" <!-- Adjust this value -->
    ...
/>
```